# How to get models from a collection that have a certain attribute

Tags: backbone.js, model

I'd like to get some models in my collection that have the attribute unit. My current method involves this,

```
        var unitIds = ciLocal.where({unit: !null});
        console.log(unitIds.length);
```

The weird thing is that removing ! returns 58 (the total minus those that unit is not null) values while the code above returns 0.

Can anyone suggest a good way to loop my collection and return those models that have anything in unit?

Its probably worth mentioning that unit contains two values, one being unitID and the other being an array of more values. I need to get the whole model back and not just the unit section.

In this screenshot you can see that 68 has null while 69 has object.
[image]

{"carID":"37","unit":{"unitID":"37_Chaffinch_75","positionHistory":[{"lat":"51.474312","long":"-0.491672","time":"2011-07-08 11:24:47","status":"1","estimatedSpeed":"0","lastSoundFileName":"Car park Exit","lastSoundRange":"10","lastSoundTime":"2011-07-08 11:25:03","isToday":false,"minutesAgo":1028188}]},"registration":"CJ-361-YG","color":"Luxor","phone":"","model":"SDV8"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [_.filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) on your collection to specify a custom validation function.

> **filter** _.filter(list, iterator, [context])
>   Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that pass
>   a truth test (iterator).

Something like this should keep the models with a defined, non null value

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection([
    {id: 1, unit: 1},
    {id: 2, unit: null},
    {id: 3}
]);

c.filter(function(model) {
    var v = model.get('unit');
    return ((typeof(v)!=='undefined') && (v!==null));
})
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/84L2R/

Comment: hi,i tried this, correct me if im wrong but i replaced c with ciLocal and tried this. When i logged ciLocal i still had all my models left. Ill try to post a screenshot of the data structure.

Comment: The models attributes and structure are defined by the JSON. I posted an entry that includes a unit object

Comment: Well, I modified my Fiddle with your data and I get the expected result http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/84L2R/2/ Could you modify my Fiddle to reproduce you problem?

Comment: Im not sure how to, there's obviously something im missing here. Ill let you knoe if i get it working and tick your answer.

Comment: Okay my collection appears as a child instead of backbone.collection so i converted it and your code runs fine. Many thanks.